Unable to edit field properties in Azure AI Search vector index
I have successfully built a vector index in Azure AI search and I will be connecting it to Azure OpenAI. However, when I build the index, I don't get an option to edit which fields are filterable, sortable, facetable, and searchable.

It is important that I am able to filter and sort the index by some of the fields (e.g. rec_year) for the final solution.
Does anyone have an idea of how to edit, it.
When I try to edit the Json directly, I get the following error:

Any ideas?

When you build the index you have to clarify it, depends on SDK or REST it could have different enabled/disabled by default. Regardless of any kind, you cannot edit it afterwards https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-what-is-an-index#field-attributes

Although you can add new fields at any time, existing field
definitions are locked in for the lifetime of the index. For this
reason, developers typically use the portal for creating simple
indexes, testing ideas, or using the portal pages to look up a
setting. Frequent iteration over an index design is more efficient if
you follow a code-based approach so that you can rebuild the index
easily.
The APIs you use to build an index have varying default behaviors. For
the REST APIs, most attributes are enabled by default (for example,
"searchable" and "retrievable" are true for string fields) and you
often only need to set them if you want to turn them off. For the .NET
SDK, the opposite is true. On any property you do not explicitly set,
the default is to disable the corresponding search behavior unless you
specifically enable it.

If you are using REST, it should be straightforward to set up
### Create a new index
POST {{baseUrl}}/indexes?api-version=2024-07-01  HTTP/1.1
  Content-Type: application/json
  Authorization: Bearer {{token}}

    {
        "name": "hotels-quickstart",  
        "fields": [
            {"name": "HotelId", "type": "Edm.String", "key": true, "filterable": true},
            {"name": "HotelName", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false},
            {"name": "Description", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable": false, "analyzer": "en.lucene"},
            {"name": "Category", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": true, "facetable": true},
            {"name": "Tags", "type": "Collection(Edm.String)", "searchable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": false, "facetable": true},
            {"name": "ParkingIncluded", "type": "Edm.Boolean", "filterable": true, "sortable": true, "facetable": true},
            {"name": "LastRenovationDate", "type": "Edm.DateTimeOffset", "filterable": true, "sortable": true, "facetable": true},
            {"name": "Rating", "type": "Edm.Double", "filterable": true, "sortable": true, "facetable": true},
            {"name": "Address", "type": "Edm.ComplexType", 
                "fields": [
                {"name": "StreetAddress", "type": "Edm.String", "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable": false, "searchable": true},
                {"name": "City", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": true, "facetable": true},
                {"name": "StateProvince", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": true, "facetable": true},
                {"name": "PostalCode", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": true, "facetable": true},
                {"name": "Country", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": true, "facetable": true}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-get-started-rest?tabs=azure-cli#create-an-index
